# No compatible GPUs found for path tracing ?? Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 1536 MB (Mac)

Tags: gpu, osx

Anyone know how to GPU render in this mac

MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)

2,3 GHz Intel Core i5

Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 1536 MB

I would appreciate any information

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange Fran! Unfortunately the Iris Plus Graphics aren't the kind of GPU that Blender requires for path tracing. A dedicated graphics card is needed (Nvidia and AMD cards are supported). Here's the entry in the Blender manual with more info: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Comment: Thanks for the info